# Unselect last pallet when selecting a new Pallet

Tags: javascript, html

I've been kind of stuck on this for a little bit and im in need of some assistance. I'm trying to make it where when I select a pallet it unselects the last selected pallet then selects the new one. I had an idea to do it but I feel like there's a more efficient way going about this.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Doll</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    #penguinDoll {
        background-color: #003366;
    }
    #palletes {
        width: 332px;
    }
    #penguinColorName {
        color: #000;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: medium;
    }
    .tinyPallete {
        border: 2px solid #000;
        border-radius: 5px;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .tinyPallete:hover {
        border: 2px solid #f6bd56;

    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function loadPalletes() {
        let colorIndexNum = 0;
        for(let palletes in penguinColors) {
            let colorHex = penguinColors[palletes],
                colorIndex = palletes, colorIndexCurrNum = ++colorIndexNum;
        
            $('#palletes').append(`<div onclick="selectPallete('${colorHex}', '${colorIndex}', ${colorIndexCurrNum});" class="tinyPallete" style="background: #${colorHex}"></div> `);
        }
    }

    function selectPallete(colorHex, colorName, currIndex) {
        //colorSelected = true;
        //$(this).css('border', '2px solid #f6bd56');
        $("#penguinColorName").text(colorName);
        $("#penguinDoll").css('background-color', colorHex);
    }
    
    //let colorSelected = false;
    let penguinColors = {
        "Blue": "003366",
        "Green": "009900",
        "Pink": "FF3399",
        "Black": "333333",
        "Orange": "FF6600",
        "Yellow": "FFCC00",
        "Dark Purple": "660099",
        "Brown": "996600",
        "Red": "ff6666",
        "Dark Green": "006600",
        "Light Blue": "0099CC",
        "Lime Green": "8AE302",
        "Gray": "93A0A4",
        "Aqua": "02A797",
        "Arctic White": "F0F0D8"
    };
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="loadPalletes();">
    <div id="form">
        <div id="penguinColorName"></div>
        <img id="penguinDoll" src="C:/Users/BossH/Downloads/doll.png">
        <div id="palletes"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

If anyone can give me some pointers on a good approach for this that would be much appreciated,

Comment: can you explain little bit more

Comment: Yeah so basically when you have another item selected it deselects that one and selects the new one you currently selected. I only want one option to be selected at a time.

Comment: `<script>`s should go right before the closing `</body>` tag, not in HEAD. Also, don't use  `onload="loadPalletes();"` - just call `loadPalletes()` in your script. Avoid using inline on* handlers in HTML. JS should be in one place only and that's the respective tag or file.

Comment: What you are trying to implement is basic browser behaviour for [radio groups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Doll</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    #penguinDoll {
        background-color: #003366;
    }
    #palletes {
        width: 332px;
    }
    #penguinColorName {
        color: #000;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: medium;
    }
    .tinyPallete {
        border: 2px solid #000;
        border-radius: 5px;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .tinyPallete.active {
        border: 2px solid #f6bd56;
    }
    .tinyPallete:hover {
        border: 2px solid #f6bd56;

    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function loadPalletes() {
        let colorIndexNum = 0;
        for(let palletes in penguinColors) {
            let colorHex = penguinColors[palletes],
                colorIndex = palletes, colorIndexCurrNum = ++colorIndexNum;
        
            $('#palletes').append(`<div onclick="selectPallete('${colorHex}', '${colorIndex}', ${colorIndexCurrNum}, this);" class="tinyPallete" style="background: #${colorHex}"></div> `);
        }
    }

    function selectPallete(colorHex, colorName, currIndex,id) {
        //colorSelected = true;
        
        $('.tinyPallete').removeClass('active');
        $(id).addClass('active');
        $("#penguinColorName").text(colorName);
        $("#penguinDoll").css('background-color', colorHex);
    }
    
    //let colorSelected = false;
    let penguinColors = {
        "Blue": "003366",
        "Green": "009900",
        "Pink": "FF3399",
        "Black": "333333",
        "Orange": "FF6600",
        "Yellow": "FFCC00",
        "Dark Purple": "660099",
        "Brown": "996600",
        "Red": "ff6666",
        "Dark Green": "006600",
        "Light Blue": "0099CC",
        "Lime Green": "8AE302",
        "Gray": "93A0A4",
        "Aqua": "02A797",
        "Arctic White": "F0F0D8"
    };
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="loadPalletes();">
    <div id="form">
        <div id="penguinColorName"></div>
        <img id="penguinDoll" src="C:/Users/BossH/Downloads/doll.png">
        <div id="palletes"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

set `active` class on selected item and remove other item `active` class

Comment: Awesome thanks. I had the idea but I wasn't really confident with it

Answer (score 1):

I realize you already have an accepted answer, but here's a slightly different implementation of the same basic idea: toggling an `active` class on the selected item.

```js
function loadPalletes() {
  let colorIndexNum = 0;
  for (let palletes in penguinColors) {
    let colorHex = penguinColors[palletes],
      colorIndex = palletes,
      colorIndexCurrNum = ++colorIndexNum;

    $('#palletes').append(`<div onclick="selectPallete('${colorHex}', '${colorIndex}', ${colorIndexCurrNum});" class="tinyPallete p-${colorHex}" style="background: #${colorHex}"></div> `);
  }
}

function selectPallete(colorHex, colorName, currIndex) {
  //colorSelected = true;
  //$(this).css('border', '2px solid #f6bd56');
  $("#penguinColorName").text(colorName);
  $("#penguinDoll").css('background-color', colorHex);
}

//let colorSelected = false;
let penguinColors = {
  "Blue": "003366",
  "Green": "009900",
  "Pink": "FF3399",
  "Black": "333333",
  "Orange": "FF6600",
  "Yellow": "FFCC00",
  "Dark Purple": "660099",
  "Brown": "996600",
  "Red": "ff6666",
  "Dark Green": "006600",
  "Light Blue": "0099CC",
  "Lime Green": "8AE302",
  "Gray": "93A0A4",
  "Aqua": "02A797",
  "Arctic White": "F0F0D8"
};

function onPaletteClick(e) {
  e.currentTarget.querySelector('.active')?.classList.remove('active');
  if (e.target.classList.contains('tinyPallete')) {
    e.target.classList.add('active');
  }
}

document.querySelector('#palletes').addEventListener('click', onPaletteClick)

loadPalletes();
```

```css
#penguinDoll {
  background-color: #003366;
}

#palletes {
  width: 332px;
}

#penguinColorName {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: medium;
}

.tinyPallete {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .1s;
}

.tinyPallete.active {
  transform: scale(.8);
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 3px white, 0 0 6px 4px yellow;
}

.tinyPallete:hover {
  border: 2px solid #f6bd56;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form">
  <div id="penguinColorName"></div>
  <div id="palletes"></div>
</div>
```